# Possible to use thin, sharp monospaced font in NetBeans 11?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-11

I really liked the default look of the code font that was used in NetBeans 8. See screenshot below. To me it was really sharp and easy to read.

In NetBeans 11 though, the font is quite blurry, and it also looks bold even though the style is not set to bold.

Is it possible to configure NetBeans 11 in some way, so that it will use a sharp font, as in NetBeans 8?

If you zoom in, you can see that in both versions, the text is anti-aliased, so it should not have anything to with anti-aliasing settings.

I guess it may have to do with the JDK and environment used. I run Ubuntu 19.

Examples:

NetBeans 8:

[image]

NetBeans 11:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was a bug in the JDK,
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8212071
which according to this page
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NETBEANS/Font+Rendering+Issues
was fixed from JDK 11.0.6.

I tried updating to Oracle JDK 13.0.2 and now the font looks good again.